# WLS - Not able to start the server

Tags: java, linux, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am not able to start WLS 12.1.3 in Linux machine, When I am trying to start the WLS server from my domain I am getting the below error, please suggest what will be the root cause for this issue.

```
<WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: A 
MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no orii in java.library.path
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post 
construct                                                                                                                      on weblogic.t3.srvr.PreConfigBootService

A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no orii in java.library.path
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct                                                                                                                      on weblogic.t3.srvr.PreConfigBootService

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:447)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:                                                                                                                     456)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate                                                                                                                     (AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelConte                                                                                                                     xt.java:82)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl                                                                                                                     .java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl                                                                                                                     .java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.one                                                                                                                     Job(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run                                                                                                                     (CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.                                                                                                                     java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor                                                                                                                     .java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused By: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no orii in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
        at com.oracle.jrockit.management.ThreadInfo.<clinit>(ThreadInfo.java:12)
        at jrockit.ext.ThreadInfo$1.run(ThreadInfo.java:19)
        at jrockit.ext.ThreadInfo$1.run(ThreadInfo.java:17)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at jrockit.ext.ThreadInfo.<clinit>(ThreadInfo.java:16)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.action.MemoryAllocationMethod.in                                                                                                                     itializeGetAllocatedBytesMethod(MemoryAllocationMethod.java:72)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.action.MemoryAllocationMethod.<i                                                                                                                     nit>(MemoryAllocationMethod.java:30)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.action.MemoryAllocationMethod.ge                                                                                                                     tInstance(MemoryAllocationMethod.java:37)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.action.MethodMemoryAllocationSta                                                                                                                     tisticsAction.<clinit>(MethodMemoryAllocationStatisticsAction.java:46)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationLibrary.loadInstr                                                                                                                     umentationEngineConfiguration(InstrumentationLibrary.java:217)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationLibrary.getInstru                                                                                                                     mentationLibrary(InstrumentationLibrary.java:124)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationManager.getAvaila                                                                                                                     bleMonitors(InstrumentationManager.java:359)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationManager.<init>(In                                                                                                                     strumentationManager.java:154)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationManager.getInstru                                                                                                                     mentationManager(InstrumentationManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.rtsupport.InstrumentationSupport                                                                                                                     Impl.getMonitor(InstrumentationSupportImpl.java:64)
        at weblogic.diagnostics.instrumentation.InstrumentationSupport.getMonito                                                                                                                     r(InstrumentationSupport.java:413)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.<clinit>(ServletRequestI                                                                                                                     mpl.java)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at weblogic.kernel.FinalThreadLocalList.initialize(FinalThreadLocalList.                                                                                                                     java:44)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.PreConfigBootService.start(PreConfigBootService.java                                                                                                                     :83)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerSer                                                                                                                     vice.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                                                                     java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                                                                                                     sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(Reflec                                                                                                                     tionHelper.java:1017)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java                                                                                                                     :388)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:                                                                                                                     456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate                                                                                                                     (AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelConte                                                                                                                     xt.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl                                                                                                                     .java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl                                                                                                                     .java:87)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.one                                                                                                                     Job(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run                                                                                                                     (CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.                                                                                                                     java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor                                                                                                                     .java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
<Apr 21, 2017 2:01:25 PM BST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.>
<Apr 21, 2017 2:01:25 PM BST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down.>
<Apr 21, 2017 2:01:25 PM BST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.>
<Apr 21, 2017 2:01:25 PM BST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000238> <Shutdown has completed.>
```

I have installed WLS 12.1.3 in Linux machine but I am not able to start the WLS in Linux machine.

Comment: Which user you had used for installation and which user are you trying this now?

Comment: Installed with root user and starting with sudo users

Comment: Login to `root` and grant file permissions for all files in the config folder to your user.